# how to invoke program by command-line options?

Tags: c, getopt

I have a program called make is to be invoked with command-line-options:

```
make  [command-line-options]  [targetname]
```

The options are:

-C directoryname: before commencing execution, make is to change directory to the indicated directory.

-f filename: instead of reading its specification from the default makefile, make reads its specification from the indicated file.

-i: ignore the unsuccessful termination of actions; continue executing a target's actions even if any fail.

-n: print (to stdout) each shell-command-sequence before it is to be executed, but do not actually execute the commands.

-p: after reading in the specification file, print its information to stdout. Then exit with success.

-s: execute silently, do not print each shell-command-sequence before it is executed.

How can I use calls of `getopt()`, `chdir()`, and `exit()` to achieve it?

Below is the code I complete so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#define bake

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int     opt;
        string  sDirectory;

        opterr = 0;
        while (opt = getopt(argc, argv, bake)) != -1)
                switch(opt)
                        {
                        case '-c':
                                int rc = chdir(sDirectory.c_str());
                                break;
                        case '-f':

                                break;
                        case '-i':
                                clean:
                                        -rm -f *.o;
                                        break;
                        case '-n':

                                break;
                        case '-p':

                                break;
                        case '-s':
                                break;
                }
        if (argv < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "file: #s [-d] [progname] failed", progname);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return 0;
```

Comment: [man getopt](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt).

Comment: are you trying to write a program that pasrses options or are you trying to run a program and pass options to it?

Comment: Note that `make` is a rather well-known program and creating your own program with the same name but different purpose and options is going to lead to confusion, and probably sooner rather than later.  Choose another name if at all possible.

Comment: There are numerous questions on SO showing the basic use of `getopt()`.  (That said, finding a high-scoring Q&A that shows the basics of `getopt()` isn't so easy — score one for the now defunct Documentation.)  One key point is that multi-character constants like `'-c'` are not portable, and `getopt()` returns single characters, not multi-character constants.

Comment: Your #define of bake suggests that this code doesn't compile. Please submit code that compiles cleanly. Also, please use a sensible tab size (2 or 4) for your code.

Comment: Also note that `getopt` is pretty old.  There are many much better options.  (`popt` and `argp_parse`, for example)

Comment: I'm fairly sure that getopt returns the actual letter found without the leading dash, but you are best off reading the documentation. You can learn a lot on a unix box by typing man getopt!

Comment: How does this compile without errors around `case '-c'`: ?

Comment: @Micromuncher Implementation-defined multi-byte character constants.

Comment: @dbush - thank you so much for sharing the link, i will read and implement myself first

Comment: @pm100 - Yes, I am trying to write a program name bake and parsing the options to it

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Thanks for the info. As it prefers '-c' as common-line-options rather than 'c', how can I achieve it?

Comment: The `getopt()` function expects to see `-c` but reports that it has seen it by returning `'c'`.  As shown in examples, and other answers here on SO.